# nodejs iterate through array of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm using nodejs and I'm trying to parse some result coming from the database. How can I make this work?

```
var data = [
    {ID: 5},
    {ID: 8},
    {ID: 13}    ];

for (var row in data) {
    alert(row.ID);
}
```

I need to get 5, 8 and 13.

Comment: you need to use data[row].ID

Comment: This is stuff you'll learn when you read a beginner's JavaScript book or tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var k in data){
    var row = data[k]; 
    alert(k+" "+row.ID);
}
```